# What does the sign means to a table in the Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I just want to know **what is meant by the sign/statement** at the beginning of the record.

Screenshot of Table 1 : it has the '*' and the '(new)' word. What is meant by that?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ZF1oqH0s9hemtYX0NpLWhqLWs/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Screenshot of Table 2 : this table only has the '*' sign. What is meant by that?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ZF1oqH0s9hd3dKdUhkQXR3VzA/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Say I want to make Table 2 become like Table 1, what should I do?

Comment: The * and (new) just means that this is the place where you can add a new row to the table.

Comment: You posted the same image twice.

Comment: Robin to @RedX : "Opps, I'll edit that."

Comment: The (New) indicates that a new ID will be generated in that field as it is an Autonumber. The star indicates a new record that has not yet been added to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(New)` is written in the fields where the value will be auto generated. If you enter the `DesignView` of a table you can change the data type of the fields in that table. If you set the type to `AutoNumber` there will be a placeholder displayed when creating new entries.

[image]

will result in a display like this:

[image]

as opposed to setting it to something different than AutoNumber:

[image]

resulting in

[image]

The leading `*` has already been explained in the comments properly: it is an indicator for a new row entry.

To make table2 like table1 you would have to change the field type to AutoNumber - unfortunately that is not possible as far as I can tell since you already have entered data:

[image]

> Once you enter data in a table, you can't change the data type of any field to AutoNumber, even if you haven't yet added data to that field.

The only way would be to a create a new table with the correct schema and move the data there without specifying the AutoNumber value.

Comment: Thanks, very well explained.