# Is there anymore instead of these 2 behavior of a table?

Tags: ms-access

[What does the sign means to a table in the Microsoft Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131719/what-does-the-sign-means-to-a-table-in-the-microsoft-access)

Referring to the link above,
I conclude that there are 2 kinds of table in MS Access:

1. Table with **' * ' sign**
2. Table with **' * ' sign** and **'(new)' sign**

Is there anymore kind of table that I should know? Perhaps the 3rd kind?

EDIT: Is there anymore "visual queues..." that I should know as a User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asterisk is showing where the new record in the table will be entered. (Table level)

The (New) is the placeholder for an Auto-Number datatype. (Field Level)

These are not indications of different types of tables.  These are different visual queues for table and field entries.

Comment: Thanks 4 helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix things up. There is one kind of table only (for each version of the database engine).

What you label "another kind of table" is just a table with an AutoNumber field. Such a field can be added at any time to a table without it. Nothing special.

Comment: I believe you are right. My problem is, I could not find the suitable words to describe the issue but thanks to @Rdster - it is called _"different visual queues for table and field entries"_. I only wish to seek is there anymore _"visual queues..."_ I should know as a User.